# Accessing json objects with spaces in html table

Tags: python, html, json, django

Apologies if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm super new to html/java/django but I feel like this shouldn't be this hard and is a stupid question but I'm going crazy over it. I'm making a web app that pulls json data from firebase so I'm using python/pyrebase/django etc. and I simply need to access a json object from my database and put it into an html table. It all works great, except accessing the child that has spaces in it (unfortunately I need to keep the spaces in for my mobile app purposes). I assumed it would be the same at dot/bracket notation but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried declaring a variable `<script> var score = 'JUDGE A     RUN 1: '; </script>`  and using `result.score` with no luck but maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot or something silly.

```
<div class="container">

        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>            
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BIB</th>
                <th>Ridername</th> 
                <th>Stance</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for result in data%}
            <tr> 
                <td>{{ result.bib }}</td> <! works! >
                <td>{{ result.ridername }}</td> <! works! >
                <td>{{ result.stance}}</td> <! works! >
                <td>{{ result['JUDGE A RUN 1: '] }}</td> <! doesn't work :( >
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

The data looks like this:

```
data = [ 
    {
        'JUDGE A RUN 1: ': '10', 
        'JUDGE A RUN 2: ': '11', 
        'JUDGE A RUN 3: ': '13', 
        'JUDGE B RUN 1: ': '13', 
        'JUDGE B RUN 2: ': '14', 
        'JUDGE B RUN 3: ': '15', 
        'bib': '01', 
        'category': 'ProMen', 
        'ridername': 'Test', 
        'score': '-', 
        'stance': 'R'
    }, 
    {
        'JUDGE A RUN 1: ': '20',
        'bib': '02', 
        'category': 'ProMen', 
        'ridername': 'Tester', 
        'score': '-', 
        'stance': 'G'
    }
]
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: There's only one space between `A` and `RUN` in the data, but you have 5 spaces in `result['JUDGE A     RUN 1: ']` (the comment viewer collapses them).

Comment: In the original data, there's 5. but I've tried with 1 and 5 and 4 actually ha

Comment: I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Only one of your results has those properties, so you'll get blanks on the other rows.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the data accurately.

Comment: That shouldn't matter but I fixed it anyways

Comment: I don't see the fix. It still says `JUDGE A<space>RUN 1` rather than `JUDGE A<5 spaces>RUN 1`

Comment: done. both the data and the code should look as you requested.

Comment: `result.score` should be `result[score]`.

Comment: `result.score` will return the value of the `'score':` property.

Comment: There is no way to do that, one way to do this is a for loop. A normal approach will through a parse error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it using the normal approach, one way to do it is:

```
{% for k, v in data.items %}
   {% ifequal k "JUDGE A RUN 1: " %}
       {{ v }}
   {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

That simply checks that if there is any key that matches `JUDGE A RUN 1:`, then show value

Comment: YES! Just change the 'data' to 'result' and works great! Thank you!